# How do i tell where the time is spent in the thread call stack for a .NET memory dump?

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory-dump

We've got some high CPU on a ASP.NET app, so i took a mem dump, and found some interesting info:

[image]

I'm not a crash dump expert.. so looking for clarity here.

Is this saying:

- Thread 29 took 11 minutes of CPU time
- It's got to do with the 'StackifyProfiler' class? (we use Stackify Retrace as an APM tool on our server)

I'm trying to work out if StackifyProfiler is the problem, or it's just 'in the call stack' of some code that has a problem.

Any tips on how to get to the bottom of it of where the CPU time is spent?

Tech:

- ASP.NET 4.5 app
- Hosted on Azure App Service
- Using Stackify Retrace as a webjob/extension

Thanks

Comment: Can you run the program through a profiler? That would be far far more useful than looking at a dump of the program after the fact.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen unfortunately i can't replicate this high CPU problem on my local instance. This is a memory dump from a production application, whilst under stress (and running on Azure, which has the Stackify profiler installed)

Comment: What is a "thread stack"?

Comment: @Enigmativity the call stack for the thread? i've edited title..

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot see where time is being spent after the fact. If method A spends time and then calls a method B that is essentially free, or if method A which is essentially free calls method B that then spends time will look identical in your results, there is no way for you to determine if it's A or B that is spending time when all you got is the timing total. You either need to guess, or run the program through a profiler, or you have to add logging code so that you can get some extra information from the production environment. (last bit is a good idea unrelated to this problem)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen damn.. okay that's kinda annoying. What _can_ we see from the data though? Just to confirm some assumptions. Is this report is saying that thread took 11 minutes of CPU time?

Comment: That definitely looks that way but interpreting dumps on this level is not my forte so better if someone else gives you answer to that, but yes, it looks that way to me.